# Error 'LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE file request rejected due to restrictions on access.' when using the S3ToMySqlOperator Apache Airflow operator

Tags: python, amazon-s3, airflow, amazon-rds

I am trying to use the Apache Airflow S3ToMySqlOperator operator ([documentation](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-mysql/stable/_modules/airflow/providers/mysql/transfers/s3_to_mysql.html)) to insert contents of a certain S3 file to a AWS RDS SQL database. The code I use for this looks like this:

```
s3_most_recent_file_to_sql = S3ToMySqlOperator(
   s3_source_key='s3://housing-project-airflow/house-links/filtered-links-most-recent/filtered_most_recent.csv',
   mysql_table='housing_project_db.city_info',
   mysql_duplicate_key_handling='REPLACE',
   task_id='s3_most_recent_file_to_sql',
   aws_conn_id='aws_s3_connection',
   mysql_conn_id='sql_conn_id',
   dag=funda_scraper_dag)
```

The 'mysql_conn_id' has as the 'login' in the connection the AWS RDS admin account. Now when running this in a DAG, I get the following error code:

*MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError: (2068, 'LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE file request rejected due to restrictions on access.')*

Now my guess is that the admin account doesn't have the permissions to load any files into the given database/table. This is confirmed when I check the admin user privileges in DBeaver; the 'file' privilege is not selected.

So now I'm trying to add this FILE privilege for the admin account, but I can't get it done.

What I've tried is to connect to the RDS SQL server with: *mysql -h housing-project-db.ckvznkgqispo.eu-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com -P 3306 -u admin -p*, after which I run the command:

GRANT FILE ON mysql.* TO 'admin'@'housing-project-db.ckvznkgqispo.eu-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com' IDENTIFIED BY 'mysecretpassword’;, after which I get

*You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IDENTIFIED BY 'mysecretpassword’' at line 1*

When I search for others who've had this problem they offer this as the solution, so I don't get why I'm getting a syntax error at all... Am using MySQL server version 8.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's a bit late for you, but others may try to enable `allow_local_infile` . please check Airflow documentation [here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-mysql/stable/connections/mysql.html). Basically, you add `allow_local_infile` parameter to Extras section in you MySQL Airflow connection details.

Answer (score 0):

With an older airflow version, I had to set `local_infile` in extra when setting up a connection in airflow ui.